# ui:include inside TabView: first ajax call in tab doesn't fire (commandButton action)

Tags: ajax, jsf, action, actionlistener, tabview

The code below is the tabView, followed by the structure of the loaded page. For the commandButton, I have tried actionListener, different combinations of render and update referencing the target inputtextarea (req) explicitly, etc. The action works fine when the form runs in its own page (not within a tab).

In the "preRenderView" event, I initialize data structures, which are populated when the form displays. Problem is when I click on the Preview button. Normally the action fires, the handling method assembles the data for display in the preview inputextarea (req), and it's displayed.

Strangely, when I click the button, the action is NOT called, although there is activity calling my other tabs' loadReqEvents, and in the outer page hosting the tabView. I suspect this is a request-response nuance of JSF that I'm unaware of. Thanks for help.

```
<p:tabView id="tbv" dynamic= "true" activeIndex="#{sessionController.activeTab}" styleClass="tabview-style">       
  <p:tab id="rtmTab" styleClass="tab-style" title="RTM" closable="false" titletip="Requirements Traceability Matrix">
      <ui:include src="url(./../rtm.xhtml"/>
   </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="composeTab" styleClass="tab-style" title="#{sessionController.composeTabTitle}" rendered="#{sessionController.crudTabRendered}" closable="false" titletip="Composition Form">
      <ui:include src="url(./..#{sessionController.composeUrl}.xhtml"/>
   </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="objTab" styleClass="tab-style" title="Object / Data Model" closable="false" titletip="Object and Data Model View">
      <ui:include src="url(./../objView.xhtml"/>
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>  
</p:layoutUnit>


<p:layoutUnit id="formLayout" position="center" gutter="0" styleClass="form-layout"> 
  <h:form>
    <f:event listener="#{attrDefController.loadReqEvent}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>  
    <p:panel style="background-color:rgb(222,231,254);width:925px;height:98%;margin-top:-4px;margin-left:-8px">
      <h:panelGrid columns="7" style="margin-right:-8px" cellpadding="2">
          <h:commandButton id="preview" value="Preview" action="#{attrDefController.previewReqAction}" style="width:100px; margin-top:2px">
             <f:ajax execute="@form" render="req"/>
          </h:commandButton>
       </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
   </h:form>
 </p:layoutUnit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the markup for where the component `req` is declared, I assume that it exists in one of the xhtml files specified in the `ui:include`.

The problem is that the `render` attribute of the `f:ajax` is specifying an id which does not exist on the page.  The reason for this is that is that the components client ID will be prefixed with the client id of its parent `UINamingContainer`.

Not all JSF components are a UINamingContainer, `form` definitely is which is why you will typically see the ID of the form prefixed to the client id of a component.  Eg:

```
<h:form id="formone">
  <h:outputText id="textComponent" value="YO" />
  <h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax update="textComponent" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form id="formtwo">
  <h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax update=":formone:textComponent" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

In the above example the client ID of `textComponent` is actually `formone:textComponent`.  Now the command button in the example above can still reference it by its Actual ID because it happens to be in the same `UINamingContainer` as its sibling component.

The commandButton in the other form however must access it by its full client id because it is not a sibling of `textComponent`.  It does this by prefixing the client ID with the universal selector `:` and then following that with the entire client ID of the `textComponent`.

Now what does this have to do with your problem?

The PrimeFaces TabView component happens to be a `UINamingContainer` as well.

So that means that to Ajax render the component with ID `req` you will need to specify an ID for your form and call it in this way...

```
render=":formid:tbv:req"
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for input maple_shaft...very much. But I don't think this is the problem. I've used "render" and "upate" in every conceivable way to reference... The action is not invoked when it's the first action on the page... After any interaction with the page, clicking on a radio button without an ajax call, for instance, and then clicking on the Preview button works fine. It's when I click on the Preview button... or any ajax enabled control...first. tbv is in a layoutUnit (not in a form). I've tried render=":tbv:attrForm:req" and update with no luck. It's as if the page isn't initialized yet...

Comment: @user2134012 What version of Primefaces are you using, because I seem to remember there being a bug with Ajax processing from one `layoutUnit` to another?

Comment: 3.3, same in 3.5. Notice I use preRenderView, which could have something to do with it. I had issues in another tab with referencing into layouts; that's when I learned to fully qualify the reference to get "update" to work. Hence why I don't think it's that. I noticed in debug that components on other tabs also aren't being submitted to the server on this first ajax action...while they ARE on subsequent actions... It's as if I need to update the tbv when page first loaded...the tbv is not in a form, btw, it's in a layoutUnit. Also beans are Session to solve bean re-creation issue in JSF 1.2

Comment: @user2134012 You are using JSF 1.2?  Hmmm... any possibility that you can upgrade to 2.1?  I know that in both MyFaces and Mojarra that hundreds of issues have been resolved and this could very well be one of them.  I can't explain why it wouldn't work the first render but work okay the second.

Comment: Sorry...dyslexia... I'm using myfaces-bundle 2.0.11... I installed both primefaces 3.5 and the latest JSF 2.2 snapshot with no luck, then I reverted back to 3.3 and . I'm beginning to think it's a focus/navigation issue. It seems like once the initial loading is done, focus is taken away from the tab, and the first click is really just giving the "page" (within the tab) initial focus. Before moving to tabs, I used the action in one page to load the next via faces_config.xml navigation. Is there any way to force focus on a tab's content? (I'm already setting the activeTab).

Comment: Hey maple_shaft... solved! Thanks for banging heads with me ... I was about to give up on tabs! Here's what was happening: In tab #1 I have a datatable. On Row select, data is updated in the bean managing the tabview; setPropertyActionListener is in the .xhtml in tab #1. A BUTTON in tab #1 triggers the display of tab #2 with data loaded, etc. What I decided to do was MOVE the button OUT of tab #1 (was co-located with datatable) to the .xhtml that hosts the tabView. Now when I select the row in Tab #1 datatable, and click on the Edit button (now outside in tabView's .xhtml) works. Thanks again!